# estimating the surface area of a steam coil immersed in a tank

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, heat-exchanger, steam

I've been tasked to design a steam coil that will be immersed into a tank in order to maintain the fluid temperature above 25C (but not to exceed 40C), and I need to calculate its surface area & length. The fluid is a highly viscous oil additive and it's not agitated.

My approach was the calculate the total energy needed to heat the coil, using $Q = m.c_p\Delta T$. where m is the mass of fluid in the tank, $c_p$ is the specific heat capacity of the fluid, and $\Delta T$ is the difference between the initial temperature of fluid (25C) and what it should be maintained at (~35-40C).

Then I equated this energy to $UA\Delta T_m$, the energy delivered by the steam, where $U$ is the overall heat coefficient for steam, $A$ is the outer surface area of the coil and $\Delta T_m$ is the log mean temperature difference.

I am assuming this approach is correct, but I'm doubting my calculations because

1. It doesn't match with [Immersion Coil Surface Area Calculator For Heating with Steam](http://www.titanmf.com/immersion-coil-surface-area-calculator-for-heating-with-steam/)
2. It seems quite large

Apart from the temperatures I've mentioned above, these are the only parameters I've been provided with from the company:

- inner diameter of the tank = $3.35\,m$
- outer diameter of the tank = $3.6\,m$
- height of tank = $6.5\,m$
- density of the fluid = $850\,kg/m^3$
- viscosity of the fluid = $30, 000\,Cst$
- pressure at which steam enters the pipe = $150\,psi$
- Heat time of $2\,hours\,(7200s)$
- pipe diameter of $2'' (0.0508\,m)$

So here's the calculation I did:

$M_{fluid} = V * \rho = \frac{PI * 3.35^2 * 6.5}{4} * 850 = 49000\,kg$

Assuming the $C_p$ to be $1800\,J/kg.K$,

$Q = 49000 * 1800 * (40 - 25) = 1.323\,GJ$

I estimated $\Delta Tm$ to be $86$ using:

$\frac{(ΔT_1 - ΔT_2)}{ln(ΔT_1/ΔT_2)}$

With $T_1$ being the inlet steam - the final temperature of the fluid = 145 C.
With $T_2$ being the outlet 'steam' - initial temperature of the fluid = 45 C (I estimated the outlet 'steam' to be around 100.

Taking the $U factor$ to be 100 ([estimated from this site](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/heat-transfer-coefficients-coils-d_178.html)),

A = 1.323 GJ / (100 * 86 * 7200) = $21m^2$.

And the corresponding length would be $\pi DL = A$ and $L = 131m$. Clearly something (or a few things) are wrong here since I don't think the tank can be that big so help would be appreciated on where I went wrong.

Comment: The T1 T2 paragraph is very unclear to me.

Comment: https://checalc.com/solved/tankcoil.html I used this as a reference.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to consider is that pipes used for heating like this are normally « finned » to increase the surface area - fins can be small discs fitted to the pipe or even wire loops - both increase the surface area massively and reduce the length required.

This article explains the finned pipe although they are collecting heat: [The performance of a coiled finned-tube heat-exchanger submerged in a hot-water store: The effect of the exchanger's orientation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030626199190038Y).